# Search for lines with a small range of angles in OpenCV

Tags: opencv, hough-transform

I'm using the Hough transform in OpenCV to detect lines. However, I know in advance that I only need lines within a very limited range of angles (about 10 degrees or so). I'm doing this in a very performance sensitive setting, so I'd like to avoid the extra work spent detecting lines at other angles, lines I know in advance I don't care about.

I could extract the Hough source from OpenCV and just hack it to take min_rho and max_rho parameters, but I'd like a less fragile approach (have to manually update my code w/ each OpenCV update, etc.).

What's the best approach here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, i've modified the `icvHoughlines` function to go for a certain range of angles. I'm sure there's cleaner ways that plays with memory allocation as well, but I got a speed gain going from 100ms to 33ms for a range of angle going from 180deg to 60deg, so i'm happy with that.

**Note** that this code also outputs the accumulator value. Also, I only output 1 line because that fit my purposes but there was no gain really there.

```
static void
icvHoughLinesStandard2( const CvMat* img, float rho, float theta,
                       int threshold, CvSeq *lines, int linesMax )
{
    cv::AutoBuffer<int> _accum, _sort_buf;
    cv::AutoBuffer<float> _tabSin, _tabCos;

    const uchar* image;
    int step, width, height;
    int numangle, numrho;
    int total = 0;
    float ang;
    int r, n;
    int i, j;
    float irho = 1 / rho;
    double scale;

    CV_Assert( CV_IS_MAT(img) && CV_MAT_TYPE(img->type) == CV_8UC1 );

    image = img->data.ptr;
    step = img->step;
    width = img->cols;
    height = img->rows;

    numangle = cvRound(CV_PI / theta);
    numrho = cvRound(((width + height) * 2 + 1) / rho);

    _accum.allocate((numangle+2) * (numrho+2));
    _sort_buf.allocate(numangle * numrho);
    _tabSin.allocate(numangle);
    _tabCos.allocate(numangle);
    int *accum = _accum, *sort_buf = _sort_buf;
    float *tabSin = _tabSin, *tabCos = _tabCos;

    memset( accum, 0, sizeof(accum[0]) * (numangle+2) * (numrho+2) );

    // find n and ang limits (in our case we want 60 to 120
    float limit_min = 60.0/180.0*PI;
    float limit_max = 120.0/180.0*PI;

    //num_steps = (limit_max - limit_min)/theta;
    int start_n = floor(limit_min/theta);
    int stop_n = floor(limit_max/theta);

    for( ang = limit_min, n = start_n; n < stop_n; ang += theta, n++ )
    {
        tabSin[n] = (float)(sin(ang) * irho);
        tabCos[n] = (float)(cos(ang) * irho);
    }



    // stage 1. fill accumulator
    for( i = 0; i < height; i++ )
        for( j = 0; j < width; j++ )
        {
            if( image[i * step + j] != 0 )
                        //
        for( n = start_n; n < stop_n; n++ )
                {
                    r = cvRound( j * tabCos[n] + i * tabSin[n] );
                    r += (numrho - 1) / 2;
                    accum[(n+1) * (numrho+2) + r+1]++;
                }
        }



    int max_accum = 0;
    int max_ind = 0;

    for( r = 0; r < numrho; r++ )
    {
        for( n = start_n; n < stop_n; n++ )
        {
            int base = (n+1) * (numrho+2) + r+1;
            if (accum[base] > max_accum)
            {
                max_accum = accum[base];
                max_ind = base;
            }
        }
    }   

    CvLinePolar2 line;
    scale = 1./(numrho+2);
    int idx = max_ind;
    n = cvFloor(idx*scale) - 1;
    r = idx - (n+1)*(numrho+2) - 1;
    line.rho = (r - (numrho - 1)*0.5f) * rho;
    line.angle = n * theta;
    line.votes = accum[idx];
    cvSeqPush( lines, &line );

}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you use the Probabilistic Hough transform then the output is in the form of a cvPoint each for lines[0] and lines[1] parameters. We can get x and y co-ordinated for each of the two points by pt1.x, pt1.y and pt2.x and pt2.y.
 Then use the simple formula for finding  slope of a line - (y2-y1)/(x2-x1). Taking arctan (tan inverse) of that will yield that angle in radians. Then simply filter out desired angles from the values for each hough line obtained.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's more natural to use standart HoughLines(...) function, which gives collection of lines directly in rho and theta terms and select nessessary angle range from it, rather than recalculate angle from segment end points.